# Descriptive statistics for R-data in a long format

Tags: r, dplyr, format, pivot

I have data on repeated measurements (5 or less) which include blood pressure measurements. I formatted the data in a long format, but seeing as I've done this for the first time, I now no longer see how to get descriptive statistics of my variables.

My example data:

```
questiondata <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
                                      3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8), 
                               time = c("time1", "time2", "time3", "time5", "time1", "time2", "time3", "time5", 
                                        "time1", "time2", "time3", "time5", "time4", "time5", "time4", "time5", 
                                        "time4", "time5", "time4", "time5", "time4", "time5", "time4", "time5"), 
                               cohort = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
                               systolicBP = c(102, 137, 132, 150, 152, 146, 160.5, 159.5, 144, 138, 137.5, 163, 
                                              137, 147, 125, 141, 147, 150, 148, 167.5, 153.5, 164.5, 159, 123), 
                               diastolicBP = c(56, 99, 78, 90, 77, 78, 80.5, 82, 72, 70, 67.5, 61, 86, 90, 80.5, 
                                               84, 75, 81, 91, 96, 80, 87.5, 87, 79), 
                               egfr = c(78.2, NA, 55.8, NA, NA, NA, 87.6, NA, NA, NA, 75.6, 70.9, 71.9, 71.8, 
                                        47.9, 36.6, 93.7, 81.5, 93.2, 82.1, 92.9, 79.1, 66.6, 55.2)), 
                          row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Which corresponds to the following tibble:

```
# A tibble: 24 x 6
      id time  cohort systolicBP diastolicBP  egfr
   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1 time1      1       102         56    78.2
 2 1 time2      1       137         99    NA  
 3 1 time3      1       132         78    55.8
 4 1 time5      1       150         90    NA  
 5 2 time1      1       152         77    NA  
 6 2 time2      1       146         78    NA  
 7 2 time3      1       160.        80.5  87.6
 8 2 time5      1       160.        82    NA  
 9 3 time1      1       144         72    NA  
10 3 time2      1       138         70    NA  
11 3 time3      1       138.        67.5  75.6
12 3 time5      1       163         61    70.9
13 4 time4      2       137         86    71.9
14 4 time5      2       147         90    71.8
15 5 time4      2       125         80.5  47.9
16 5 time5      2       141         84    36.6
17 6 time4      2       147         75    93.7
18 6 time5      2       150         81    81.5
19 7 time4      2       148         91    93.2
20 7 time5      2       168.        96    82.1
21 8 time4      2       154.        80    92.9
22 8 time5      2       164.        87.5  79.1
23 9 time4      2       159         87    66.6
24 9 time5      2       123         79    55.2
```

So for example now I want to

- Get how many persons are in each cohort
- What is the mean of the systolicBP, in total, for each cohort, and at each timepoint.

I'm sure this is very easy, but I can't seem to get any viable results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
questiondata %>% 
  group_by(cohort) %>% 
  summarise(n = n_distinct(id),
            mean_systolic = mean(systolicBP, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   cohort     n mean_systolic
#>    <dbl> <int>         <dbl>
#> 1      1     3          143.
#> 2      2     6          147.


questiondata %>% 
  group_by(cohort, time) %>% 
  summarise(mean_systolic_time = mean(systolicBP, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   cohort time  mean_systolic_time
#>    <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>
#> 1      1 time1               133.
#> 2      1 time2               140.
#> 3      1 time3               143.
#> 4      1 time5               158.
#> 5      2 time4               145.
#> 6      2 time5               149.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

```
questiondata %>%
  group_by(cohort, time) %>%
  summarise(mean_systolic_time = str_c(round(mean(systolicBP, na.rm = TRUE), digits = 0), " mmHg"),
            .groups = "drop")

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  cohort time  mean_systolic_time
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>             
1      1 time1 133 mmHg          
2      1 time2 140 mmHg          
3      1 time3 143 mmHg          
4      1 time5 158 mmHg          
5      2 time4 145 mmHg          
6      2 time5 149 mmHg
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you say there is a convenient way to add a character to values of a column of the tibble? for example 'mmHg' for the mean_systolic_time column?

Comment: Updated the response. Is that what you want to do? You should know that after adding "mmHg", the result will be a text, not a number.

Comment: Yes. ideally I was thinking of adding something shorter like 

`mutate(across(contains("BP"), ~[stringer function adding a string]))`

But I can't seem to find a str_ function that does this. Your workaround is helpful as well.

Comment: I couldn't think of a better one `summarise(across(contains("BP"), ~str_c(round(mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), digits = 0), " mmHg")), .groups = "drop")`

Comment: When I add `%>% mutate(contains("BP"), ~str_c(., "mmHg"))`  after the summarise then I get an error that says `across() must only be used inside dplyr verbs`. I don't get why.. `str_c` should work this way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234202/discussion-between-tcvdb1992-and-yuriy-saraykin).

Comment: Thanks! Something weird with my script happened so CTRL+ENTER did not work anymore. Resolved it, code works fine now. I've clicked the box that you answered y question.